# what is the difference between these two statements in php?

Tags: php, reference, arrow-functions

I was reading about arrow functions in php documentions and I came across this code

`fn&($x = 42) => $x;`

`fn(&$x) => $x;`

what is the difference between these two statements and what they do ?

Comment: the use of & in a function declaration indicates you are passing the parameter by reference

Comment: The first has a default value; the second uses the source's underlying reference. So that means `$foo = 5; $add10 = fn(&$x) => $x + 10; $add10($foo); echo $foo;` gives `15`, because it used the same reference that stores `$x`'s value.

Comment: fn($x = 42) : is a function with one or 0 parameter, if 0, default value 42

fn(&$x) : is a function with one parameter passed as reference, meaning if changed in the function, the new value of $x will be pass in the main.

Answer (score 4):

in the second you use `&$x` and that's passing a variable by reference. it calls `reference by value`

so the `$x` out of the function will change if you do something in the function.

[reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

here the final value of `$a` is `5`:

```
$a = 5;
$y  = fn ($x) => $x++;
$y($a);
echo $a;//5
```

but in `reference by value`, the final value of `$a` changed and it's `6`:

```
$a = 5;
$y  = fn (&$x) => $x++;
$y($a);
echo $a;//6
```

So you can see in reference by value, the original value of the variable can be changed

Comment: `$a = 5;  echo (fn (&$x) => ++$x )($a);` is the shorter version of my example

Answer (score 1):

`&` sets a reference to the variable
`fn($x = 42)` : is a function with one or 0 parameter, if 0, default value 42

`fn(&$x)` : is a function with one parameter passed as reference, meaning if changed in the function, the new value of $x will be pass in the main.